# In egrep, how to click a matched line and let it show the matched line in another buffer without moving the cursor

Tags: compilation, rgrep

In notepad++, I could search a folder, and then click the match line to display the matched line of the corresponding buffer. How to do this in emacs?

What I can do now is to press "ENTER" on the matched line. But that moves the cursor to the other window with the matched data. But I don't want to move the cursor. Is this doable? Or anyway to click the matched line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the process of reviewing the grep matches smoother by using the emacs way of interacting with the `*Compilation*` family of buffers.

This solution does not specifically solve your question on how to show the matched line *without moving the cursor* but it helps you navigate the *grep* results as probably intended in emacs.

Here are the steps:

1. Run grep using `M-x grep`. For the sake of example, let's say you are running *grep* in your `~/.emacs.d/` and you enter the grep arguments as `require *.el`.
2. Now here are few default bindings and commands that will help you navigate the results in a convenient manner **while the point is in the actual file buffer on the matched line**:

   - `M-x next-error` to navigate to the next grep result. The default bindings are `M-g M-n` or `` C-x ` ``.
   - `M-x previous-error` to navigate to the previous grep result. The default binding is `M-g M-p`.
   - `M-x first-error` to navigate to the first grep result.

*Do not be confused by the term 'error' in the functions above. It is a generic term used in *Compilation* buffers.*